# How to create a function that makes instances of multiple different abstract classes in PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to build the following code, but i cannot understand how to define the instance variable, because it is an object

```
function getInstance($productName)
{   

    switch ($Name) {
        case Name1:
            $instance = new Class1();
            break;
        case Name2:
            $instance = new Class2();
            break;
        case Name3:
            $instance = new Class3();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return $instance;
}
```

Comment: you could create an array of name => classname values, and use $Name to get the matching classname, and then $instance = new $classname;

Comment: Can you explain your problem in more details because the question is unclear now.

Comment: I created a file, in which different classes are defined based on the type of different products (that is my database). So, i have 4 different classes corresponding to 4 different categories. I want to write a function, which creates an instance of each class. However, i do not know how to define the instance variable before the switch statement

Comment: `$instance` must be `null`. I updated my answer.

Comment: @A.Developer do not forget to mark the answer or add your if there no the right answer. This question can be useful for other in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define it as `null`. Also you can throw an exception in situation when `$productName` is not in the list.

Example:

```
<?php

class Class1 {}
class Class2 {}
class Class3 {}

function getInstance($productName)
{
    $instance = null;
    switch ($productName) {
        case "Name1":
            $instance = new Class1();
            break;
        case "Name2":
            $instance = new Class2();
            break;
        case "Name3":
            $instance = new Class3();
            break;

        default:
            throw new \Exception("Unknown type ($productName)!");
            break;
    }

    return $instance;
}

echo get_class(getInstance("Name1"));
```

Comment: I implemented it, but it returned null instead of the object

Comment: getInstance() must return `null` if you requesting an object which is not described in it. You can't get an object if you do not know what an object you must create. (-;

Comment: Thank you! I got this exception. Does it mean that the name of the product i inserted does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you .. though I am not clear about your making instance, but you can define it as null.

```
function getInstance($productName)
{   
    $instance = null;

    switch ($productName) { // $Name should be productName
        case Name1:
            $instance = new Class1();
            break;
        case Name2:
            $instance = new Class2();
            break;
        case Name3:
            $instance = new Class3();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return $instance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Read how to use Reflection
2. Read how it works in PHP http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php

It will solve your problem.

```
<?php 
function getInstance($productName){
    $productToClass=["product1"=>"class1","product2"=>"class2","product3"=>"class3"];
    return new ReflectionClass('Object\'.$productToClass[$productName]); 
}

?>
```

Comment: I got the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''Object\'.$productToClass[$pro' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE)